# repeat element by javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I want to repeat these elements:
contain a cell and select menu bring data from the database through while

```
<div id="orginal">
<td width="99">
    <select name= "certificate"  id="xx" 
    onchange="BK.Ajax.Updates('newfile.php?id='+document.getElementById('xx').value,'ajx');" size="1">
        <option>.....</option>
        <?
        $sql_company=mysql_query("select * from company");
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_company))
        {
            echo "<option value='$row[id]'> ";
            echo $row['name'] ;
            echo "</option>";
        }
        ?></select>

    </td>
```

in another div:

```
<div id="wrapper">
</div>
```

Using Javascript code:

```
<script language="javascript">
function repeat()
{
var el = document.createElement('div');
var oldHTML = document.getElementById('orginal').innerHTML;
el.innerHTML = oldHTML;
document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML = el;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are trying to do or what your problem is.

Answer (score 3):

The `innerHTML` property is for setting HTML (string) to the element. If you want to add an element object itself, you need to use `.appendChild()`

Replace

`document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML = el;`

with

`document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(el);`

Comment: It doesn't work .. My friends ..I want when pressed on the image, for example, to repeat the form